# retrieving the report's parameters dynamically

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

is there a way to retrieve a *JasperReports*'s report with its parameters?

which means that we don't have to know the parameters to retrieve the report in our application.The parameters prompts can also be embedded in our application.

Once the report is embedded in our application and if we want to run it, the parameters prompts are displayed automatically as if they were in the *JasperRepoprts Server*.

Comment: please can anyone help me with any suggestions ?

Comment: I am not clear what you exactly want. 1. Do you want a report with optional parameter, i.e. the user may or may not provide a value? Or 2. Do you want to provide the parameter via your programming and make it seemless for the user?

Comment: To add, both of which can be done in Jasper

Comment: I want to retrieve the report and its parameters using REST web services in my own application (not jasper), without having to know the reports parameters.(I'm looking for a web service or something like that by which I can retrieve both, taking into account that we don't know the report parameters at the retriving moment).

Comment: I can explain more:If a report has a parameter, we have to provide this parameter and append it to the web service in order to retrieve the report.Now, I don't want to provide this parameter.I want the webservice to retrieve the pop up that will prompt me to enter the parameters, and then I can retrieve the report.I wish that it is clear now for you.Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, got it now. I will post the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is called Jasper HTTP API ([Link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/embedding-using-http-api))

You basically build a URL for your jasper report. I am assuming you are hosting the Jasper Reports server.
You can use this URL via any iFrame in the HTML.

If you see the parameters below, you can choose to skin the report (which will remove any extra components), add themes to suit your application etc. You can pass the parameters via the REST format e.g.. `&projectId=221`

[image: Various parameters in the URL]

If you want a pop up:

1. In the JRS, go to Edit the report.
2. In Controls and Resources, you can add a control input, if you want.
3. This will basically show you the popup and you can enter the value.

[image]

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is not what I'm looking for exactly.Using the Iframe we should also pass parameter to retrieve the report.I'm looking for a method by which I can retrieve the report without passing any parameter.I want to see the pop pup in my own application after calling the web service, not in the jasper server.Thanks in advance

Comment: If you mean you should be able to see a pop up in your application, then writing that logic is up to you. Jasper does not invoke your application code. It has API's which you can use to program your application to open a window. Short answer is this is not a ready made functionality. The second part of my answer will give you a pop up, but it is inside the Jasper report window. 
You could parse the URL and filter out the number of parameters, and then write a logic to open a window.

Comment: Thanks for your response san .I have tried your solution and it works fine with the jasperReport Library.I'm looking now for something stronger.I have found in JasperSoft embedding guide that there are  newer features of the JasperReports Library that allow interactive reports where tables can be sorted or filtered by the user.

Comment: I didn't found relevant information in the web related to the JasperReports Libraries (the java libraries) that I should use in order to program the retrieval of the reports in my own application.I'd like to have the possibility to retrieve the report filters  as well, then apply them to filter my reports in my own application.Thanks in advance for any suggestion.